# exclude inactive users when sending push notifications

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

Does apns or gcm notify clients (us) when certain device ids are inactive?

Or should we try to guess who is inactive and active?

I guess there are many user accounts who actually deleted our app. I want to remove those devices from our server so that we don't have to send push notifications to them..

(or should we not care?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Apple provides a Feedback service for this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html

For GCM, it is built-in in the response of the GCM HTTP connection server:
https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html